# AVR-libc `uart_putchar` implementation

Tags: avr, c, avr-gcc

In  [AVR-libc page 143](https://cours.polymtl.ca/inf1900/logiciel/progAvr/avr-libc-user-manual-2.0.0.pdf) the implementation of the function `uart_putchar()` is typical as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream);

static FILE mystdout = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);

static int
uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
if (c == '\n')
  uart_putchar('\r', stream);
loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA, UDRE);
UDR = c;
return 0;
}
int
main(void)
{
  init_uart();
  stdout = &mystdout;
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I know that we can redirect a specific stream to a `stdout` or `stdin` using `fdevopen()`.

But is not the variable `stream` is not used in this function?
Why is there such a variable that not used by the function? Is that because the `fdevopen()` pointers to functions parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifically creating a UART stream. You are creating a generic stream that happens to go to the UART.

Many times streams can go to different places. As the variable type `FILE` suggests it's commonly to a file - such as on an SD card. In these situations the `FILE` parameter is essential for the function to know exactly where the data is to go to.

For the UART it is irrelevant since there is only one place it *can* go - the UART.

The functions that interact with whatever you implement expect a certain prototype and pass certain parameters. Whether you use those parameters or not you have to accept them and have them in your function prototype - otherwise you just can't compile your code (you have a mismatch in the function pointer definitions).

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler throw a warning at compile time because of that unused variable?

Comment: @NAND It is used in this case - it's passed to the recursive line feed / cr call. Plus not all compilers have it turned on by default.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there such a variable that not used by the function?

The first parameter of [`fdevopen`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gab599ddf60819df4cc993c724a83cb1a4) takes a parameter of type

```
int (*)(char, FILE*)
```

which is a pointer to a function that returns `int` and which takes two arguments: One of type `char` and then one of type `FILE*`.

Consequently, when providing (the address of) a putter function to `fdevopen`, that function must have the same signature, even if some argument is unused.
Same applies to the first argument of `FDEV_SETUP_STREAM`, which is used to initialize some `FILE` object, and where the respective component also has that type.

Strictly speaking, parameter `stream` *is used* in the example because it is passed down to a self-call of `uart_putchar`. If it was really unused, you could do the following:

- C++: Omit the parameter name like in `int uart_putchar (char c, FILE*) { ... }`
- C++17, C23: Mark the parameter with attribute `[[maybe_unused]]`.
- GNU-C, GNU-C++: Mark the parameter with `__attribute__((__unused__))`.
- Add a line `(void) stream;`.

All these means tell a reader that the parameter is unused, and they tell the compiler that it's fine that the parameter is unused so the compiler will not throw a diagnostic at you.